# How to translate this sentence from Euler's Dissertatio?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, mathematics, neo-latin

At the beginning of *Dē frāctiōnibus continuīs dissertātiō*, Euler writes the following:

> Variī in Analysin receptum sunt modī quantitātēs.

*in Analysin* just means *in Analysis* but the rest of the sentence is a bit odd to me.

> Variī receptum sunt modī quantitātēs.

Indeed *receptum* is singular while *variī*, *sunt*, *quantitātēs* are plural.
How should I parse this sentence?

**Edit.** *receptum* should be *receptī*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the whole sentence.
Reading from [this scan](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/71/), I get:

> Varii in Analysin recepti sunt modi quantitates, quae alias difficulter assignari queant, commode exprimendi.

It might be easier to parse if I reorder it so that the words that belong together are actually close:

> In Analysin recepti sunt varii modi commode exprimendi quantitates, quae alias difficulter assignari queant.

Now *recepti* (not *-um!*), *varii*, and *modi* are in the same form, and *quantitates* is the object of *exprimere*.
This reads as:

> In Analysis we have various ways to conveniently express quantities, which are otherwise difficult to assign.

I took some liberties translating.
More literally, *modi recepti sunt* means "ways are received (back)" — I get the feeling that for Euler the prefix *re-* here did not necessarily mean getting something back as it did in classical times — but I translated it as "we have".
This was just to conform to modern mathematical style and idiomatic English.
The same applies to *difficulter assignari queant*, which would more literally be "are difficultly able to be assigned".

And this makes a lot of sense if the topic is continued fractions, a method of expressing quantities differently than one might first expect.
And I should also add that I do like the way Euler constructed his opening sentence.
It starts with emphasis on *varii*, and the convenience of expressing is only mentioned after the difficulty of expressing otherwise.
It is a little slower to parse perhaps, but I find it to be dramatically correct in the more convoluted order.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!